# Blazor form submit needs two clicks to refresh view

Tags: webassembly, blazor

I have the following Blazor component I'm testing an API call to get weather data. The submit button needs to be clicked twice for some reason in order for the table to display the updated object's properties.

When the page initializes I get the location from the browser just fine and the weather data is displayed in the table without issue.

#### FetchData.razor

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@using BlazingDemo.Client.Models
@using AspNetMonsters.Blazor.Geolocation

@inject HttpClient Http
@inject LocationService LocationService

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>
<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<div>
    <EditForm Model="@weatherForm" 
        OnValidSubmit="@GetWeatherDataAsync">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <InputText Id="cityName" 
                   bind-Value="@weatherForm.CityName" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>
<br />

@if (weatherData == null)
{
    <Loader/>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Conditions</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>@weatherData.Name</td>
                <td>@weatherData.Weather[0].Main</td>
                <td>@weatherData.Main.Temp</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@functions {

    WeatherFormModel weatherForm = new WeatherFormModel();
    WeatherData weatherData;
    Location location;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        location = await LocationService.GetLocationAsync();

        if (location != null)
        {
            weatherData = await 
        GetWeatherDataAsync(location.Latitude,location.Longitude);
        }
    }

    protected async Task<WeatherData> GetWeatherDataAsync(decimal 
                        latitude, decimal longitude)
    {
        return await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherData> 
          ($"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" 
         + $"{location.Latitude}&lon=" 
         + $"{location.Longitude}&units=metric&appid=***removed***");
    }

    protected async void GetWeatherDataAsync()
    {
        weatherData = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherData> 
          ($"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" 
         + $"{weatherForm.CityName}&units=metric&appid=***removed***");
    }
}
```

#### WeatherFormModel.cs

```cs
namespace BlazingDemo.Client.Models
{
    public class WeatherFormModel
    {
        [Required, Display(Name = "City Name")]
        public string CityName { get; set; }

        public bool IsCelcius { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm calling the `GetWEatherDataAsync()` method and I can see the data being returned from the API on each call by inspecting Chrome's return JSON data. It just never updates the table on the first click. I've also tried setting `weatherData` to `null` before calling the method but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason the `StateHasChanged()` call was necessary here is because the `GetWeatherDataAsync()` method you were referring to is `void`. So there was no a way for the server to know when the call has completed. So the original form submit request finished earlier than the weather data was populated. Hence, the call to `StateHasChanged()` would indicate the server that there is a need to rerender the component and that would work just fine.
In general, you should simply avoid using `async void` (unless you know it's truly a `fire-and-forget` situation) and return some type of `Task` instead, which would eliminate the need for the explicit `StateHasChanged()` call.

Below, I've simply changed your `GetWeatherDataAsync` method to return `Task` instead of `void`:

```cs
protected async Task GetWeatherDataAsync()
{
    weatherData = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherData>($"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={weatherForm.CityName}&units=metric&appid=***removed***");
}
```

Comment: This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16237#issuecomment-384781166) seems to suggest that Blazor supports async event handlers and is also mentioned in the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#event-handling). Which means this is the correct answer.

Comment: @Artak - how would the refactored code look in this example?

Comment: Will add it to my answer now

Answer (score 7):

When you hit the "submit" button, the GetWeatherDataAsync() method is called, and it retrieves the data into the weatherData variable... and ends its mission...

Ordinarily, components are re-rendered after their events have been triggered; that is, there is no need to manually call the StateHasChanged() method to re-render the component. It is automatically called by Blazor. But in this case, you do need to manually add the StateHasChanged() method in order to re-render the component. Thus your code should be like this:

```
protected async void GetWeatherDataAsync()
    {
        weatherData = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherData>($"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={weatherForm.CityName}&units=metric&appid=***removed***");

        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

The "submit" event is the only event in Blazor that his action is prevented by default by Blazor. The "submit" event does not really post the form to the server. See: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Browser.JS/src/Rendering/BrowserRenderer.ts . So it seems to me..., it's only a guess, that Blazor treats it differently, and does not call the StateHasChanged method to refresh the component.

Comment: Wow, that should be part of our public docs. I'll make a suggested change. Cheers.

Comment: Excellent post, thought my form was not submitting or needed two clicks, but closer inspection with breakpoints showed it was submitting each time. Turned out it just needed this to show my confirmation message.